# Fill the table with json data using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to fill the table with json data using jQuery. But the div content stays emply. Pls help me find an error. The array `list` contains the data (I checked it with `console.log(list)` ). Also `list['Var1']` and `list['Var2']` refer to values specified by keys `Var1` and `Var2`. The problem is exactly in jQuery.

```
function loadData() {
    $.getJSON(
              'modules/getData.php',
        function(data) {    
                  var list = data.flights;
                  var textToInsert = '';
                  console.log(list);
                  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
                        textToInsert[i++]  = '<tr><td>';
                        textToInsert[i++] = list['Var1'];
                        textToInsert[i++] = '</td>' ;
                        textToInsert[i++]  = '<td>';
                        textToInsert[i++] = list['Var2'];                                                               
                        textToInsert[i++] = '</td> </tr>' ;              
                    }
                    $('#flights_table tbody').append(textToInsert.join(''));
              }
    );             
}   

<div id="flights_table" style="display:none;">
    <table id="newspaper-b" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" width = "100%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Var1</th>
                                <th scope="col">Var2</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**getData.php**

```
$list = array();
//fill the list using 'keys' and 'values'
    echo json_encode(array('flights' => $list));
    die();
```

**UDPATE:** list.length is included. But Firebug still says

> TypeError: textToInsert.join is not a function

**SOLUTION:** The solution was to use this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                       aux = list[i];
                        textToInsert  += '<tr><td>';
                        textToInsert  += aux.Var1;
}
```

Comment: It's not a function because it is a string. You declare it as such `var textToInsert = ''`. You are using it as an array, so declare it as as an array.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop `for (var i = 0; i <length; i += 1)`

You are not saying what length is! It should be `list.length`

Also, you should declare `textToInsert` as an array not a string if you want to use it as such

```
textToInsert = [];
```

Comment: Thx, I updated my code, but Firebug still says: TypeError: textToInsert.join is not a function

Comment: See my updated answer, can you also post the output from `console.log(list);`? That might help as well

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var textToInsert = new Array();
```